# Sqlite, How to check is string contained in any value in database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have username made of firstname+lastname+'some number' like "johndoe123" as a string in Android. And I have sqlite table with frequent English first and last names. Table "names" with column "firstName" and column "lastName".

- How to check is this username contain any of those from this table?
- Is it possible to do this on sqlite side or I need to send letter by letter and wait for response and check until there is no more letter or its equal to column value? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the rows from the table `names` that are contained inside the username `johndoe123` you can use the operator `LIKE`:

```
select * from names 
where 'johndoe123' like '%' || firstname || '%' or 'johndoe123' like '%' || lastname || '%'
```

Comment: What a shame, I did not know that I can use it by writing before 'like'. Really simple solution took me few hours. Thank you